# Firebase for flutter app pubpec.yaml error

Tags: flutter, firebase, build.gradle

I am a kid developer and new to programming, I am Trying to setup Firebase for my flutter android app.After setup the firebase my flutter app is not running.  I followed the official firebase for android instruction and a couple of other fairly new tutorials.  when i run the project, i got and error message as ,`Error: No pubspec.yaml file found. This command should be run from the root of your Flutter project.`

Here is my  app/build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

android {
    namespace "com.example.flutter_travel"
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.flutter_travel"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}
 plugins {
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

dependencies {
     implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.5.0')

}
```

**And this is android/build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
       classpath "com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5"


        
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

please help me to run my application.

How to setup firebase to my flutter app

Comment: Perhaps you run the the `flutter` command in `android` directory? the command should be run from the project directory. You can also use IDE extension to run the project.

Comment: go to your project folder, then what code editor you use just open terminal(android studio and vs code has built-in terminal) open terminal and write flutter pub get

Answer (score 0):

First, find out whether the `pubspec.yaml` file exists in your project or not. If the file exists, put it in the right folder directory.